# Sendig email with an attachment in Laravel 7 using mail() and fpdf

Tags: php, laravel, email, fpdf

I am trying to send email with an attachment via mail function and FPDF library.
But when I send it, the email comes just with some strings and encoded characters.

Here is my code bellow:

Code to send email

```
        $message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";
        
        // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
        $separator = md5(time());
        
        // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
        $eol = PHP_EOL;
        
        // attachment name
        $filename = "test.pdf";
        
        // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
        $pdfGenerate = new RelatorioManutencaoController();
        $pdfdoc = $pdfGenerate->imprimir(base64_encode($manutencao->id));
        // return $pdfdoc;
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
        
        $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
        
        // message
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $message.$eol;
                
        // attachment
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; 
        name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $attachment.$eol;
        $body .= "--".$separator."--";


        $sender = "diakuzena@gmail.com";
        $emissor = "diakuzena@gmail.com";
        $assunto = "Assunto do email";
        $header = 'MIME-version:1.0' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $header .= 'From:' . $sender . '<' . $emissor . '>';
        mail($sender, $assunto, $arquivo, $header);
        mail("diakuzena@gmail.com", $assunto, $body, $header);
```

Someby please help me solving this problem.

Comment: You are probably not building the correct MIME structure. Is there no php library that can take care of these details for you? If you can't use a library, look at the source of an email with a correct attachment and compare that to the source of one of your emails. Try to find the differences in the MIME structures and adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command: `php artisan make:mail` this generates a specific controller for sending mail, in the resources add the mail template and in the controller generated by the command in the `build` function include the following code :

```
public function build()
{
    // attach method with a file in your system
    return $this->view('emails.your mail template')
                ->attach('/path/to/file');
}
```

[docs of attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#attachments)!

or for inline attach in the html template add this:

```
<body>
    Here is an image:
 
    <img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToImage) }}">
</body>
```

[docs of inline-attachments](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#inline-attachments)!

to send it, just call this mail handler:

```
Mail::to($request->user())->send(new YourGenerateMailController());
```

For more information check the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Actually I want to send a pdf file not an image.
And the site is already hosted, and I don't have access to SSH terminal to execute this comand.

Comment: You can generate it manually, or generate it in your local environment and upload it to the server, in the example I also mention an image but you can send any type of file, it should not be specifically an image, I leave you the controller code:

Path: app/Mail/NotifyMail.php

NotifyMail.php 

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#via-public-properties 

just copy the html code of that section, that's the structure of the controller